# Ping results in "Host is Down" (but it's not!) error after iOS 10 Update

Tags: ios, iphone, networking

I have an iOS application that is a simple client or "remote" that sends some bytes to a hardware device when the user presses buttons within the application. The hardware device is an Arduino with a [WiFly shield RN171](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/11049). The device broadcasts an AdHoc WiFi network. Upon connecting to the AdHoc network, the iPhone will have an IP Address in the 169.254.0.0/16 subnet. The hardware device has an IP address of 169.254.1.1.

Since updating to iOS 10, the application cannot connect to the hardware device and receives the error "Host is Down". As a means of troubleshooting, I installed a generic Network Ping tool from the App Store, which yields the same error: "Host is Down" when I attempt to ping the hardware device 169.254.1.1 from the iPhone.

I can however, ping the iPhone from the hardware device.

This is a non-issue in my "development phone" which is still running iOS 9. The app happily connects to the hardware device, and the same "Network Ping" tool can ping the hardware device no problem.

I'm wondering if there are any changes in iOS 10 to the Networking tool set that might have introduced this problem? I cannot find any resources that would say so, nor am I sure how I can troubleshoot this issue...

Comment: First, you are not supposed to manually configure Link-Local addresses (169.254.0.0/16), nor are you allowed to assign Link-Local addresses via DHCP. There is a required auto-configuration using a pseudo-random number generator for the last 16 bits, and you must check for address conflicts and choose a different number when a duplicate address is detected. You are also not allowed to subnet the Link-Local address range, nor are you allowed to route Link-Local addresses. iOS 10 may object to your misuse of the Link-Local address range.

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm not sure where I stated that the hardware devices uses a DHCP server to assign the client an address. The hardware device is configured to use "Auto IP" which I believe is the proper configuration for an AdHoc network. The client (iPhone) connects to the AdHoc network that is broadcasted by the hardware device. The IP addresses I provided are purely for example purposes, but I've edited my wording as to avoid providing any misleading information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment on one of the answers, we were forced to switch the device to operate on a non-reserved subnet (e.g., 192.168.10.0) as the latest iOS update outright prevents the device from making a connection on the link-local subnet (i.e., 169.254.0.0/16). We were unsuccessful in our attempts to have the iPhone connect to the device on the link-local subnet even after enabling "NSAllowsLocalNetworking" and "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" and adding the link-local subnet to "NSExceptionDomains".

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the same hardware and also have the issue with iOS10.
There's good news and bad news.

Good news: You can solve the problem by going to the wifi settings and forget the wifi network of the RN171 module and rejoin.

Bad news: Each time you switch to another network you'll need to forget the RN171 network again and rejoin.

Hope i could help you

EDIT: i've found the proper solution. In your info.plist file you'll need to add an exception for secure connections. See:https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33

I've added these entries in the info.plist file
[info.plist entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVPbf.png)

Comment: We ended up switching the RN171's network to a non-reserved network (e.g., 192.168.10.0/255.255.255.0) and voila, the phone happily connects. The RovingNetworks official app (e.g., for firmware updates) suffered the same issue (could not connect) following the iOS10 update, so that gave us a good indication that iOS decided that the link-local subnet was off limits. Thanks, Apple. So, we published some literature that instructs our customers how to update their device firmware using an iOS9 (or ealrier) phone, from their Mac (via telnet) or from a Windows machine. Sucks, but our only option.

Comment: Same problem for us on iOS10 with TCP to 169.254.1.1. We ended up switching to using non-reserved network IP addresses (192.168.1.1) too. None of the plist options could get tcp working to 169.254.1.1 addresses. As John says - thanks for letting us know Apple!